# Can a stylus file know who imports it?

Tags: stylus

For instance:

There is a A.styl which @import B.styl

Can in B.styl there has a $file-imports-me variable get the filename of A.styl? ($file-imports-me = A)

Comment: Or can stylus know what's the current filename using some node pulgin?